# Implement MIN or get the lowest record

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to ask for help on how to fix this. I would like to add a MIN or some sort of query to only show lowest number on the TotalTime base on the SQL query below.

The query is working but it show duplicate data and I only want to get the lowest TotalTime.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name, 
  t1.Description, 
  t1.Issue, 
  t1.Dateres AS ATime, 
  t2.Dateres AS BAck, 
  TIMEDIFF(t2.Dateres,t1.Dateres) AS TotalTime, 
  t2.Acknowledge, t2.Resolution 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
  AND t1.IPAddress = t2.IPAddress 
  AND t1.Description = t2.Description 
  AND t1.Issue = t2.Issue 
  AND t1.Severity = t2.Severity 
  AND t1.Timestamp = t2.Timestamp 
WHERE t1.Dateres IS NOT NULL
  AND t2.Dateres IS NOT NULL 
  AND t2.Acknowledge = 'user@home.net' 
  AND t2.Dateres >= '2011-10-18 00:00:00' 
  AND t2.Dateres <= '2011-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY ATime
ORDER by BAck ASC;
```

Comment: Don't these tables have primary and foreign keys? You join condition is rather peculiar.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to group by `ATime` but then select fields like `Description` and `Issue` without an aggregate function? Is `Description` functionally dependent on `ATime`?

Comment: `Description` and `Issue` **and  `t2.Dateres`**

Comment: ypercube, tables don't have primary and foreign keys as they are system generated.

Comment: Mark, seems like I am getting good results by changing the group name, description, issue but I will keep on testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t1.name, 
t1.Description, 
t1.Issue, 
t1.Dateres AS ATime, 
t2.Dateres AS BAck, 
Min(TIMEDIFF(t2.Dateres,t1.Dateres)) AS TotalTime, 
t2.Acknowledge, t2.Resolution 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
AND t1.IPAddress = t2.IPAddress 
AND t1.Description = t2.Description 
AND t1.Issue = t2.Issue 
AND t1.Severity = t2.Severity 
AND t1.Timestamp = t2.Timestamp 
WHERE t1.Dateres is NOT NULL AND t2.Dateres is NOT NULL 
AND t2.Acknowledge = 'user@home.net' 
AND t2.Dateres >= '2011-10-18 00:00:00' 
AND t2.Dateres <= '2011-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY t1.name ORDER by BAck ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work:::

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name, 
t1.Description, 
t1.Issue, 
t1.Dateres AS ATime, 
t2.Dateres AS BAck, 
Min(TIMEDIFF(t2.Dateres,t1.Dateres)) AS TotalTime, 
t2.Acknowledge, t2.Resolution 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
AND t1.IPAddress = t2.IPAddress 
AND t1.Description = t2.Description 
AND t1.Issue = t2.Issue 
AND t1.Severity = t2.Severity 
AND t1.Timestamp = t2.Timestamp 
WHERE t1.Dateres is NOT NULL AND t2.Dateres is NOT NULL 
AND t2.Acknowledge = 'user@home.net' 
AND t2.Dateres >= '2011-10-18 00:00:00' 
AND t2.Dateres <= '2011-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY ATime ORDER by BAck ASC;
```

Comment: I think this is better: `TIMEDIFF(MIN(t2.Dateres),t1.Dateres)`

Comment: I tried Min(TIMEDIFF(t2.Dateres,t1.Dateres)) AS TotalTime and also TIMEDIFF(MIN(t2.Dateres),t1.Dateres) both still showing multiple records.

Comment: I want to group records and only show I results if match so I need to implement something the disregards duplicate record and only shows record with the lowest value of TotalTime. What I did is I change the grouping to GROUP BY name, description, issue, ATime and it show good now but I will observe it. thanks to Mark for pointing me.